# Incomplete syntax highliting of c++ code in Emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, syntax-highlighting

In my GNU Emacs 24.3.1 I discovered some problems with syntax highlighting.
It does not work properly for all cases. For Example:

```
double *getmyWall() const;   // is correctly highlighted 

BestSurfaceDomainWall *getmyWall() const; //is not highlighted
```

The class `BestSurfaceDomainWall` is included by a header in this file.
The strange thing is that for most of the other defined classes the highlighting is correct, and if I remove the `*` it is highlighted again.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: How is BestSurfaceDomainWall defined and does it differ from the others. Is there an example using something other than a simple type (you show double) that can be seen?

Comment: BestSurfaceDomainWall is ordinary a class with private and public members. It contains normal and virtual functions and and pointers to certain objects. As well it inherits from a base class.

Comment: The problem occurs although I include the file of its definition. But if I do a forward declaration the highlighting works.
The highlighting works for all simple types and for most of all the other classes, but fails for some of them with no recognizable pattern.